# Formatting the output stucture of a WPF application built via msbuild in a Powershell script

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, msbuild

I am currently trying to deploy a wpf app to a network location via a power shell script.  This is building and publishing to the given location fine, however I wish for the output to be formatted the same way as the visual studio publisher - with only the setup.exe and an application folder container the builds.

Currently when I publish all of the build items are included in the folder.  I was wondering if there is a msbuild property to do this?

My current command looks similar to this:

```
& $msbuild `
/p:PublishDir=NETWORK/LOCATION `
/p:Configuration=Release `
/p:CustomAssemblyName=Test `
/p:ApplicationVersion=$1.0.0.1 `
/p:ProductName=Name `
/p:BootstrapperEnabled=true `
/target:publish `
/p:CreateDesktopShortcut=true `
/p:IsWebBootstrapper=false `
/p:InstallUrl=NETWORK/LOCATION `
/p:UpdateUrl=NETWORK/LOCATION `
/p:InstallFrom=Unc `
/p:PublishWizardCompleted=true
```

This is working fine, however when it is publishing to NETWORK/LOCATION it is including all of the dlls etc in this folder.  I just wish for the output to be as below.

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was running MSBuild from the solution level not the project level.  It seems when it runs from the solution level it copies all of the dlls over with it too.